# Where to add C wire?

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel, thermostat

Would anyone be able to tell me which group of wires I add the C wire too?.
I think it’s the white one but want to make sure
Thank You

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Connect to the junction of the yellow, blue, and red wires

Since you have air conditioning, we can trace out the junction of the thin yellow and thin white wires to determine where your contactor compressor cable is; from there, we know the other end of that compressor cable goes to the C wire, and we also know that the C wire is yellow from the posted wiring diagram, so the junction of the thin red wire from the compressor contactor cable and the the thick yellow wire from the transformer, along with a thick blue wire off to another part of the unit, is your C wire junction.  Incorporate the blue wire from your thermostat cable into that, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Wow thank you very much it worked out perfectly